# Is it possible to use GitHub API to create branch protection rule for a branch that does not exist

Tags: github

Challenge: I want to disallow "master" branch creation.
For that I want to create "branch protection rule" for master branch (which does not exist), by setting `Restrict who can push to matching branches` and `Restrict pushes that create matching branches`.

I am able to create branch protection rule for existing branch using GitHub API.

I would like to create branch protection rule for branch that does not exist. That is possible using GitHub UI, but returning 404 when trying to use API.

Why I am not able to create it with API? Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way.
Instead of creating branch protection rule, I have created ruleset.